# initialize and add value to a list in dictionary at one step in Python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dictionary where key is string and value is list.

Now while adding a value associated with given key, I always have to check if there is any list yet, otherwise I have to initialize as empty list somewhat like following snippet:

```
      if not k in myDict:
          myDict[k] = []
      myDict[k].append(v)
```

I am wondering if there is any way to combine these steps into single one in python 3.7.

Comment: You may consider using [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict`)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are at least three ways:

Use `dict.setdefault`

```
>>> data = {}
>>> data.setdefault('foo', []).append(42)
>>> data
{'foo': [42]}
```

Use `defaultdict`, which unlike `.setdefault`, takes a callable:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> data = defaultdict(list)
>>> data
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {})
>>> data['foo'].append(42)
>>> data
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'foo': [42]})
```

Finally, subclass `dict` and implement `__missing__`:

```
>>> class MyDict(dict):
...     def __missing__(self, key):
...         self[key] = value  = []
...         return value
...
>>> data = MyDict()
>>> data['foo'].append(42)
>>> data
{'foo': [42]}
```

Note, you can think of the last one as the most flexible, you have access to the actual key that's missing when you deal with it. `defaultdict` is a class factory, and it generates a subclass of `dict` as well. But, the callable is not passed any arguments, nevertheless, it is sufficient for most needs.

Further, note that the `defaultdict` and `__missing__` approaches will keep the default behavior, this may be undesirable after you create your data structure, you probably *want* a `KeyError` usually, or at least, you don't want `mydict[key]` to add a key anymore.

In both cases, you can just create a regular dict from the dict subclasses, e.g. `dict(data)`. This should generally be very fast, even for large `dict` objects, especially if it is a one-time cost. For `defaultdict`, you can also set the `default_factory` to `None` and the old behavior returns:

```
>>> data = defaultdict(list)
>>> data
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {})
>>> data['foo']
[]
>>> data['bar']
[]
>>> data
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'foo': [], 'bar': []})
>>> data.default_factory = None
>>> data['baz']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'baz'
>>>
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use `dict.setdefault`:

```
>>> d = {}
>>> d.setdefault('k', []).append(1)
>>> d
{'k': [1]}
>>> d.setdefault('k', []).append(2)
>>> d
{'k': [1, 2]}
```

> Help on method_descriptor in dict:
>
> dict.setdefault = setdefault(...)
>       D.setdefault(k[,d]) -> D.get(k,d), also set D[k]=d if k not in D